# How to see the Compiled Code in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Im using Netbeans IDE 8.2 it comes with the jdk1.8.0_151 and i want to see the compiled code.I press the CTRL key and with mouse left click above the method that i want to see. Is there a way?

```
   public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> cnsmr) {
        // compiled code
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button in the top right that says `Attach Sources...`. Then either select one of the options, or click the `Download` button.